# Using TF model.predict() after model training throws unknown shape error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, normalization, transformer-model

Background: My data has shape of (batch_size, ghost_dim, data_length) and I am learning to train a MultiHeadAttention based model. I am inputting a single batch of same dimension data with model(), model.predict() or model.predict_on_batch() functions to return predictions array after fitting the model and I am getting similar shape related errors on each.

Throws:

```
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__predict_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2169, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2155, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2143, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2111, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

    **ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'layer_normalization_1' (type LayerNormalization).
    
    Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'layer_normalization_1' (type LayerNormalization):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=float16)**
```

If I used model() function call directly, there is a similar error regarding input shape during MultiHeadAttention layer with input appearing to be 1 dimension instead of the original single batch data that I am inputting, which is:

```
x_predict = np.random.normal(size=(1, 1, 512)) 

predictions = self.model(x_predict)
predictions = self.model.predict_on_batch(x_predict)
```

Not sure what is the origin of all these numpy array shape errors.. Any help/ideas appreciated?

Comment: I'm getting this as well, with a model that worked fine in a previous TensorFlow version (2.10.0). I've checked the shapes going into my LayerNormalization layer, and the rank is well-known (the input has shape `(None, 10, 5)`, which shouldn't be a problem even though the batch dimension is left unspecified). I believe this is a bug that's cropped up in a newer TensorFlow version.

Comment: Update: For me, I tracked this down to the `tf.data.Dataset` that I was passing to `model.fit` not having a defined output shape (which is apparently a problem, even though the input size was defined for the model). That doesn't appear to be the problem in your case, though, since you're training on arrays of defined shape. One thing I did notice is that your `y_train` should have shape (32, 1, 512).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Wonder if going back to a previous TF version would fix it.

Comment: y_train shape is a good catch! (error is still there though..)

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in specifying the batch in your input layer shape:

```
decoder_inputs = layers.Input(batch_input_shape=shape, dtype=tensorflow.float16)
```

Then your model will always assume that your train and test data will be formed by the defined batch_size=32. So x_predict with batch_size=1 will give an error. I would suggest to drop the batch_size from your input layer:

```
decoder_inputs = layers.Input(shape=(ghost_dim, embed_dim), dtype=tensorflow.float16)
```

Or if you can sample your x_predict data to have always the shape of (32, 1, 512).

Comment: Thanks for going through my code! Tried both, throws the same exact Unknown Rank error at LayerNormalization still. I have read other people reporting this as a TF bug and specifying even output shapes in between layers did not help either as some others suggested in other forums.. Really baffled